# Change ionic navbar backbutton behaviour ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I want to change the behaviour of back button, instead of going back to the previous page it will do something else. Is it possible?

```
 <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title center>Mobile Apps</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
```

Comment: @MohanGopi, I want to change the behaviour of back button, instead of going back to the previous page it will do something else

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5071 may be this helps you

Comment: What do you need to do? Redirect the user to a different page, prevent the user from leaving, ...?

Comment: @sebaferreras, it will be based on condition

if(condition === true){
      // stay on the page
}
else {
     // go back to previous page
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will be based on condition if(condition === true){ // stay on the
>   page } else { // go back to previous page }

You can use [NavGuards](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#nav-guards):

> In some cases, a developer should be able to control views leaving and
>   entering. To allow for this, NavController has the **ionViewCanEnter** and
>   **ionViewCanLeave** methods. Similar to Angular 2 route guards, but are
>   more integrated with NavController. For example, if you wanted to
>   prevent a user from leaving a view:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

  ionViewCanLeave(): boolean{
   // here we can either return true or false
   // depending on if we want to leave this view
   if(isValid(randomValue)){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @Parth :)